# How to disable top and bottom views in UIImagePicker iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using `cordova` default camera plugin. When I added it to my project, the camera view looks like following,

[image]

So is there any way to remove the top view(Flash and camera rotation) and Bottom view(with capture button) from the view. Please give me a way to fix this.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: you can't, the plugin is like this. But you can create your own plugin that takes pictures

Comment: ok thank you. I create a plugin by my self.